# Pygame worked yesterday but today only a Black screen appears

Tags: python, pygame

i am not a beginner in python but i am also not good in coding and i am working on a simulation of the Millikan Experiment. The code is not finished but i tried to run it several times yesterday and pygame opened a screen with the Simulation in it. Today i wanted to work on it, but as i tried to run the Code only a black screen appears. Now that i was searching for a view hours to find a solution for that Problem, i hope someone in here can help me.

Here is the Code im trying to run:

```
#Importieren der benötigten Module
import pygame as pg
from pygame.locals import QUIT
import numpy as np
import sys
import random as rand

# Definieren der Hauptvariablen
pi = np.pi
g = 9.81
eta = 18.2e-6 #Viskosität der Luft laut Wikipedia
U = 100 #Spannung muss noch festgelegt werden, wie wir sie definieren
eps = 8.854e-12 * 1.00059
d = 0.01
e = 1.602e-19
q = rand.uniform(200 * e, 200 * e)
dt = 1 / 300
rho = 910 # Dichte von Olivenöl

#Definieren der Farben
Black = (0, 0, 0)
White = (255, 255, 255)
Green = (0, 255, 0)
Red = (255, 0, 0)
Blue = (0, 0, 255)


# Definieren der Klasse der Öltröpfchen (self ist ein Platzhalter)
class Oel:
    def __init__(self, pos, lad, geschw, rad, masse):
        self.pos = pg.Vector2(pos)
        self.lad = q
        self.geschw = pg.Vector2(np.random.uniform(-1, 1), np.random.uniform(-1,     1)).normalize() * 10
        self.radius = rand.uniform(0.1, 5)
        self.masse = ((4/3) * self.radius**3) * rho
        self.rect = pg.Rect(self.pos.x - self.radius, self.pos.y - self.radius, self.radius * 2, self.radius * 2) # Rechteckfür Kollisionserkennung
    # Funktion zum Aktualisieren der Position der Öltröpfchen
    def aktualisiere_pos(self):
            if self.pos.x - self.radius <= 0 or self.pos.x + self.radius >= 800:
                self.geschw.x *= -1
            if self.pos.y - self.radius <= 0 or self.pos.y + self.radius >= 600:
                self.geschw.y *= -1
        
            # Aktualisieren der Position und des Rechtecks für die Kollisionserkennung
            self.pos += self.geschw / 60
            self.rect = pg.Rect(self.pos.x - self.radius, self.pos.y - self.radius,   self.radius * 2, self.radius * 2)

    # Funktion zur Berechnung der Gesamtkraft
    def F_R(self):
        if np.linalg.norm(self.geschw) == 0:
                self.geschw = pg.Vector2(0.01, 0.01) 

        # Festlegen der Richtung der Reibungskraft
        F_r_parallel = 6 * pi * eta * self.radius * np.dot(self.geschw, self.geschw / np.linalg.norm(self.geschw))
        F_r = F_r_parallel * self.geschw.normalize()
        v_dir = self.geschw.normalize()
        F_r_dir = np.dot(self.geschw, v_dir) * v_dir
        if np.linalg.norm(F_r_dir) != 0:
            F_r -= np.sign(np.dot(self.geschw, v_dir)) * F_r_dir
        # Definition der Kräfte
        F_g = pg.Vector2(0, self.masse * g)
        F_c = pg.Vector2(0, -q * (U / d))
        F_a = pg.Vector2(0, (4/3) * pi * self.radius**3)
        F_ges = F_r + F_g + F_a + F_c

        # Definition der Beschleunigung
        a = F_ges / self.masse

        # Aktualisierung der Geschwindigkeit
        self.geschw += a * dt

        # Aktualisieren der Position 
        self.pos += self.geschw * dt

    # Zeichnen der Öltröpfchen
    def draw(self, screen):
        pg.draw.circle(screen, Blue, self.pos, self.radius)

 # Erstellen der Öltröpfchen mit Zufallsverteilten Massen und Ladungen       
oel = []
for i in range(100): # Stückzahl
    pos = (rand.randint(100, 700), rand.randint(100, 500)) # Startposition
    lad = rand.uniform(-20 * e, 20 * e) # zufällige Startladung
    geschw = pg.Vector2(0, 0)
    rad = rand.uniform(0.1, 5)
    masse = (4/3) * pi * rad**3 * rho
    troepfchen = Oel(pos, lad, geschw, rad, masse)
    oel.append(troepfchen)  # Hinzufügen der erstellten Tröpfchen zur Liste

# Erstellen der Oberfläche
pg.init()
size = (800, 600)
screen = pg.display.set_mode(size)

# Aktualisierung des Bildschirms
clock=pg.time.Clock()

# Laufzeit des Fensters festlegen
running = True

while running:
    for action in pg.event.get():
        if action.type == QUIT:
                pg.quit
                exit()

    # Hintergundfarbe           
    screen.fill(White)
    for troepfchen in oel:   
        troepfchen.aktualisiere_pos()
        troepfchen.F_R()
        troepfchen.draw(screen)

    pg.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

I tried to replace the initiation of the Surface with parts of other codes but that wont work, so i put a printcommand in the loop and it showed me the the word i wanted to read, till i interrupted the process.
I also tried to run a finished code from someone else, it worked once but doesnt work for about 10 times.

Im working on a virtual Linux machine in Windows 11 Pro (64 Bit). The Environment im using is Microsoft Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The problem is not reproducible. You know that the code works. So what is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check what have changed in your environment.

Any VM parameters, or updates to either the Linux or Windows systems could be the cause.

However, there is a point code could help: there are ways to customize the backend pygame itself will use to do graphics: maybe not all of them have been broken  - check the docs on pygame.display.init at https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.init